# NuGetFallbackFolder path suddenly "wrong" when on a German Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I think I understand a little more of what is happening so I rewrote my question... And it seems to be somewhat different from what I described first.

This time it happened when I started a new project of type grpc server.

The symptom still is the same:
"Der Fallbackpaketordner "C:\Programme (x86)\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" wurde nicht gefunden."
Translation: The Fallbackfolder "C:\Programme (x86)\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" was not found.

However it is not finding the "german path" (still on my "german" os).
And this is what I can reproduce - so I think I got it upside down when describing it last time...

Examining this further:
In my nuget.config this entry is generated:

```
<add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Programme (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
```

If I delete it and change settings in the nuget packet managers packet sources it might get back...

While this SEEMS to right for a german OS "Programme (x86)" actually seems to be a ghost (sorry I do not know what the right term is). Because usually every reference seems to be redirected to" C:\Programm Files (x86)".
So even when I klick my way through Fileexplorer down into "Programme (x86)" - if I check the path in that "Path-Box" in Filexplorer it shows "C:\Program Files (x86)" instead.

But exactly this translation seems not to be working with nuget...
So who is setting this entry ? To me it seems like either it should be set to "Program Files" OR it should be translated which does not to seem to happen...

In Fileexplorer I can enter both paths into the path box. It does not matter if I enter "C:\Program Files (x86)" or "C:\Programme (x86)" - I always end up in the former. And that is where "\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages" is actually residing. The problem is not that that path is not existing on my system. The problem is that somehow the german notation is used when generating that entry in my nuget.config but then the translation/redirection is not working or used in the nuget package manager...

Ah and I´m not sure if the project type does matter but just in case - this time it was a grpc service.

Visual Studio 2019 16.7.5
Core 3.1

Comment: What is the version of the net core? 2.2 or 3.1?  Also, what is your VS version?

Comment: Did you have any progress?

Comment: I just updated/changed the question - the issue is still there also it seems to be somewhat different to what I first described - probably I got confused myself with all that translations happening (the path seems to be translated, I have to translate - so I got lost in translation)

Comment: Did you install the German version of the VS2019 from the vs_installer and without choose the English version? You should choose the english version at the same time. And I think you have to reinstall VS with English first to make the installed path with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\xxx` if your path is not the same.

Comment: I will give it a try - but I do not think it is (or at least it should not be) an issue of the language of Visual Studio. What I try to explain is: When the entry for the FallbackFolder is generated it seems to be considering the german OS. So it generates an entry with "C:\Programme (x86)\...'. However that path is not really existing. It is what FileExplorer does show you but it seems windows usually translates that to "C:\Program Files (x86)" which is the path that always works and seems to be the "physical" path. But that translation seems to be missed by the nuget package manager.

Comment: Just close VS, delete the global `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` and then make sure your VS is changed to  English. After that, restart VS to regenerate the file.

Answer (score 2):

It is your own issue about Net Core on your German PC. And `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk` is the system default location about VS. The default address is in English, not in German and we cannot change that.

> The Fallbackfolder "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder"
> was not found.

The `NuGetFallbackFolder` is created and required by `Net Core 2.x Sdk`. And if you use `Net Core 3.x` sdk, it does not need that folder and is not a problem any more. Since I did not know how you installed VS on the German PC, not sure whether you have the dual operating system on one PC, you should check your German system, and make sure if the folder path of `Fallbackfolder` exists.

---

**If** not, please install [Net Core 2.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) sdk on your German system, and it would install the folder `NuGetFallbackFolder`.

**And** it this does not help, please try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue on the German system:

1. Close VS, open **Control Panel**-->**Programs**-->right-click on any net core sdk program-->**Change**--> **Repair**
2. add this node in your `xxx.csproj` of your Wpf Core project.

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>true</DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
3. try to [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) on German system

Comment: I got this issue again with a new project (this time it was not WPF but a project of type grpc service... not sure if the project type matters...
I updated the question because this is what I can easily reproduce...